# Redis FT.SEARCH Pipe Escape Character

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I am using a pipe delimited value in one of my search fields.

Creating the index:
`FT.CREATE myIdx ON HASH PREFIX 1 doc: SCHEMA title TEXT WEIGHT 5.0 body TEXT url TEXT searchkey TEXT`

Set the hash values for `doc:1` :
`HSET doc:1 title "hello world" body "lorem ipsum" url "http://redis.io" searchkey "BA00000000|99|01|1"`

Set the hash values for `doc:2` :
`HSET doc:2 title "hello world2" body "lorem ipsum2" url "http://redis2.io" searchkey "BA00000000|88|01|1"`

Searching the `TEXT` field with limit range from 0 to 10

`FT.SEARCH myIdx "@searchkey:BA00000000|99|01|1}" LIMIT 0 10`

`FT.SEARCH myIdx "@searchkey:BA00000000|99|01|1" LIMIT 0 10`

**Output**:

```
1) (integer) 2
2) "doc:1"
3) 1) "title"
   2) "hello world"
   3) "body"
   4) "lorem ipsum"
   5) "url"
   6) "http://redis.io"
   7) "searchkey"
   8) "BA00000000|99|01|1"

4) "doc:2"
5) 1) "title"
   2) "hello world2"
   3) "body"
   4) "lorem ipsum2"
   5) "url"
   6) "http://redis2.io"
   7) "searchkey"
   8) "BA00000000|88|01|1"
```

`FT.SEARCH myIdx "@searchkey:{BA00000000\|99\|01\|1}" LIMIT 0 10 no results`

In the example above i am trying to find exact match for search key BA00000000|99|01|1
i tried using \ escape character no luck.

Please help

Comment: What do you mean exact match ?

Comment: Did you try to use `searchkey TAG` instead of `TEXT` when creating the search? If you need exact matches, the search field should be a tag.